# Escaping a special character within a command in shell script

Tags: regex, apache, shell

I am little new to shell scripts . I have a command in shell script which has special character in it. Now i don't know how to escape special character from each word  .

**/app/home/apache243/bin/httpd -f /app/apache$ configs/statichost1.conf**

as you see **apache$ configs** has special character and space . Now I want to escape all the special character from this command except from **/httpd -f /** . Now this special character can come before and after **/httpd -f /** . i.e it could be **apache $243** this or this **apache! 234@** . 
/httpd -f/ before and after it . What i wanted is below

/app/symc/apache243/bin/httpd -f /app/apache\$\ configs/statichost1.conf

Answer (score 0):

Write the command like this (using single quotes):

```
/app/symc/apache243/bin/httpd -f '/app/apache$ configs/statichost1.conf'
```

BTW, with questions of this kind, it always helps, if you specify for which shell you are searching an answer. While in this particular case, quoting works the same in at least all those shells I know, this doesn't need to be the case always.

Comment: This command get generated on run time it is not static . so each time the String before  **/httpd -[A-z]/** and after  gets changed . And they could contain the special character . And it is like escaping special character from each word of command except  **/httpd -[A-z]/** . @user1934428  .it is a bash shell .

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
 if we have a variable in shell script with value like this

**var=/app/home/apache243/bin/httpd -f '/app/apache$configs/statichost1.conf'**
and we try to execute (Specific to Apache Server configuration)

**$var -S**

will not work . At least for me it didn't work
but doing this

**eval $var -S**
worked for me